# Is it possible to change notification bar on Android Pie?

Tags: notification-bar, 9.0-pie

[image]

Hi. After updating Samsung Galaxy J7 2018 to Android 9.0(Pie), my notification bar changed. So is there any way to change icons order
(justify clock to the other side).

NOTE: My phone is not rooted.

Comment: it is the android 9 feature to place clock on the left.

Comment: so, it can not be changed?

Comment: Android version 6 had such features which is not available in android 9. May be it requires a root permission to change clock position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do that. Download Good Lock 2019 and install Quickstar. You can move the clock back to right, or even hide it. You also can hide/unhide other icon on the status bar.

If you are unable to use Good Lock, there is alternative. Download an app called "Nice Lock". Then you need to manually download and install "Quickstar apk" from apkmirror. After that, open Nice Lock and from there open Quickstar.